# Как зеркально повернуть bmp-изображение?

Tags: php

Нужно чтобы код сделат такой переворот исходника[image: введите сюда описание изображения] ,а не как сейчас [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я ума не приложу, как это сделать помогите пожалуйста.

```
 <?php
                       $fp = fopen("example1.bmp","r");
                       $data = fread($fp,54);
                       $biWidth = (((((ord($data[21])) + ord($data[20]))) + ord($data[19]))) + ord($data[18]);
                       echo "Ширина: ".$biWidth."<br/>"; 
                       $biHeight = (((((ord($data[25])) + ord($data[24]))) + ord($data[23]))) + ord($data[22]);
                       echo "Высота: ".$biHeight."<br/>"; 
                       $dobavka = (4 - (($biWidth * 3) % 4)) % 4;
                       echo "Добавка: ".$dobavka."<br/>"; 
                       $fp1 = fopen("examplenew1.bmp","w");
                       fwrite($fp1,$data);
                       for($i=0;$i<$biHeight;$i++)
                        $imgdata[$i]=fread($fp,$biWidth * 3 + $dobavka);
                       for($i=0;$i<$biHeight;$i++)
                        fwrite($fp1,$imgdata[$biHeight - $i - 1]);
                       fclose($fp1);
                       fclose($fp);
                      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, для примера установлю `MIME` тип в заголовке на `BMP`

```
header('Content-type: image/bmp');

//Загружаем изображение
$img = imagecreatefrombmp('example1.bmp');

//Отражаем по горизонтали
imageflip($img, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);

//Выводим изображение
imagebmp($img);

//Освобождаем память
imagedestroy($img);
```

Для работы `imageflip` необходима версия `php` >= 5.5.0
Подробнее о `imageflip` [тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imageflip.php) и о работе с изображениями [тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.image.php)

Comment: Суть в том, что мне нужно именно, с помощью функций работы с файлами это нужно реализовать, никак иначе, да, я в курсе, что можно с помощью флипа это все, но я работаю напрямую с байтами в картинке.